How to create video by stitching together images (.png) where the serial on each image file increases by 6
I am trying to create a video (preferably mp4) from a series of png images. However, the name of each image file increases by 6 every frame. For example, I would have depthframe_0000 as the first frame, and depthframe_0001 for the next frame.
There are a few answers that have answered a similar question but I am unable to process the video when the image files are not increasing by 1.
I would like to keep the fps at 5. I am using ffmpeg as the suggested in the answers above but am open to any other suggestion.
The collab code that I have put together is as follows:
import subprocess

# Define the frame rate and the input/output paths
output_fps = 5
input_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/depth/depthframe_%04d.png"
output_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/depth.mp4"

# Create a list of the frames
frames = [input_path % i for i in range(0, 2671, 6)]  # Update range as needed

# Write the list of frames to a temporary text file
with open('frames.txt', 'w') as f:
    for frame in frames:
        f.write(f"file '{frame}'\n")

# Create the command
command = [
    "ffmpeg",
    "-f", "concat",
    "-safe", "0",
    "-i", "frames.txt",
    "-c:v", "libx264",
    "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
    output_path
]

# Run the command
subprocess.run(command, check=True)


if this is a ffmpeg CLI question, SO is the wrong site for it. ffmpeg probably has a way to tell it to just do this += 6 for the indices, right on the command line. if not, your approach of generating a text file listing them is just fine. -- if this is an actual coding question... use PyAV, do not run subprocesses. -- your code contains no OpenCV, your question contains no occurrences of "cv" at all. I'll remove the tag. please do not add tags solely to gain the attention of better eyeballs. a tag is a promise of content. there is no opencv content here.

Thanks Christoph, appreciate the advice.
